# Orthogonality of vectors and its dependence on the inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, physics, inner-products

Consider a set of vectors, $\{{\bf e}_i\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am thinking specifically of the standard orthonormal basis. I am having a very difficult time understanding what it means for vectors to be orthogonal. Apparently, this is an inner product-dependent concept. However, I am very used to this being a physical concept. Can you help me separate the two?

Consider two different Euclidean structures for the sake of comparison. Put $\langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_ix_{i+1}$. Call this $B_1({\bf x},{\bf y})$. One can show it is a symmetric, positive definite, bilinear form and therefore a Euclidean structure. Now put $\langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle$ = $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$. Call this $B_2({\bf x},{\bf y})$, yet another Euclidean structure.

We can speak of real Euclidean vector spaces equipped with either $B_1$ or $B_2$.

I am to understand that the components in the formulas for $B_1$ and $B_2$ come off of the same standard orthonormal basis, correct? That is, for each ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we may express the vector on $\{{\bf e}_i\}$ as ${\bf x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i {\bf e}_i$. These $x_i$'s are the same ones as in the formulas for $B_1$ and $B_2$. ${\bf e}_1$ is the vector defined as ${\bf e}_1 = (1,0,0,\cdots,0,0)$.

I can use the bilinear form to induce a norm and hence speak of lengths and angles between vectors. If I use $B_2$, I find that $b_{2ij} = \langle {\bf e}_i, {\bf e}_j \rangle$ yields a diagonal matrix of all 1's. Therefore, $\{{\bf e}_i\}$ is the standard orthonormal basis, and is in fact orthonormal in physical space.

Now if I use $B_1$, I find that all ${\bf e}_i$ have length $\sqrt2$, and that the angle between adjacent ${\bf e}_i$ must be $120^{\circ}$ and is $90^{\circ}$ between all others. This is where I am utterly confused. Why should $\{{\bf e}_i\}$ depend on the defined inner product? I thought these were physically orthogonal and unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are they still given such that ${\bf e}_1 = (1,0,0,\cdots,0,0)$?

What's invariant here? Shouldn't the value of $\langle {\bf x}, {\bf x} \rangle$ be invariant no matter how I define it since it gives me the lengths and angles between vectors? These should be physically invariant quantities no matter what basis I use.

As you can see, I am having trouble reconciling physical orthonormality with mathematical orthonormality. Apparently, mathematical orthonormality is with respect to some arbitrarily defined inner product (a symmetric, positive definite, bilinear form). Could you please help clarify?

Comment: There is no such thing as "physically orthogonal" in mathematics.

Comment: So basis vectors that are angled 90 degrees with one another may or may not be orthogonal?

Comment: For that matter, is there even a notion of length in mathematics? The inner product induces a norm, but the actual real number that the norm returns means nothing unless we compare it to another vector. The "length" of a vector must be relative to something. In physics, lengths are given units such as meters or feet for a physical conception of the vector.

Comment: No, vectors are orthogonal iff thez are angled 90 degrees to one another. However, the **angle** is defined by the inner product.

Comment: Sure there is a notion of length in mathematics. The norm is precisely that. You can take two vectors and compare which one is "bigger" by seeing which one has a bigger norm.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you're thinking of a vector space, as a physicst might put it, "in coordinates." That is, you're *naming* your vectors by $n$-tuples of real numbers from the very start, by considering the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. This can obscure one's view of which concepts are "intrinsic" to the notion of a vector space. Try phrasing your question for an *abstract* vector space (or inner product space) instead. If you can do this successfully then you will find you've answered the question!

Comment: Thanks ebrahim. My main issue though is that we define the inner products with the coordinates of vectors, as I did in the original question for $B_1$ and $B_2$. Therefore, we are forced to deal with coordinates. Is this not correct? How would we define an inner product without introducing a basis? Also, we think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ because it is isomorphic to any other real vector space.

Comment: One doesn’t always need to specify a coordinate system or a basis to define an inner product. Consider the space of one-variable polynomials $f(x)$ over the reals of degree $\le$ 3. A standard inner product for such a space is $(f,g)=\int_0^1f(t)g(t)\,dt$. That’s perfectly well defined, but we haven’t mentioned a basis or coordinates for this vector space.

Comment: You must, however, introduce a basis to evaluate the inner product.